# AngularJS Modal not working when pushing data into ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use a bootstrap modal to update some data in a list, the first modal that I am trying is to add a new item to the list.

I have succeed on creating the modal, firing the ajax call and returning the data to the main controller via the promise below.

My problem is that I can not get the new project to append to the list projects. I feel like my code below is perfect and should do the job, but it doesn't add the project in the ng-repeat

```
$scope.projects.push.apply($scope.projects,modalProject)    //doesn't add the item to $scope.projects
modalInstance.result.then(
    function (modalProject) {
        $log.info(modalProject);
        $scope.newProject = modalProject                            //works and updates the UI
        //$scope.projects.push(modalProject)                        //adds the new item to $scope.projects but doesn't get shown in the ng-repeat
        //$scope.projects.push(angular.copy(modalProject))          //doesn't add the item to $scope.projects
        //$scope.projects.push.apply($scope.projects,modalProject)    //doesn't add the item to $scope.projects
        //$scope.$apply()                                           //causes the inprogress error
        $log.info($scope.projects)
     }, function () {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed');
 }
```

The `$scope.newProject = modalProject` works perfectly though.

Feels so close to working perfectly, what's going wrong?

Will put a plunker up after lunch

Comment: Does `$log.info(modalProject);` logs the correct **modal**?

Comment: Andrei Cacio - Yes, there's only one Modal at the moment and modalProject logs exactly the data I would expect to see. Also when I use `$scope.projects.push(modalProject)` the `$log.info($scope.projects)` will include the modalProject - however the ng-repeat won't be showing it.

Comment: Try the example I've shown below and let me know if anything changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally gotten to the bottom of this issue, I will post this as the answer to hopefully avoid this post generating any confusion for anybody else.

**Answer**: The above code does work as expected.

In my scenario above, I had put a filter on the ng-repeat that I had forgotten about and the modal was using server side data to set the value that the filter was working on but it wasn't working properly. Long story short, I messed up in a not very obvious way.

Overall, I am happy as this forced me to use a factory to hold my data instead of relying on passing data around which I believe has simplified my code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the `$scope.newProject = modalProject` into a `$evalAsync` like so:

```
$scope.$evalAsync(function() {
   $scope.newProject = modalProject;
});
```

This will trigger a digest cycle and maybe your data will appear this way.

Comment: Hi Andrei, Thank you for your help. I discovered that the issue was a filter on the ng-repeat that wasn't being correctly set by the server. I will put up an answer to clarify the solution.